# Saving a webform to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've been trying to learn PHP and have been given a simple task to help me.

I'm trying to get a user to complete a form which has their email address in it, then save it to a database.

Here's my code so far:

```
<html> 
    <body>

        <form action="postemail.php" method="post"> Email Address: <input type="text" name="emailaddress" /> <input type="submit" /> 

        </form>

    </body> 
</html>

<?php 
   $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","edwardHost","password"); 
     if (!$connection) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
    mysql_select_db("my_database", $connection);

    $sql="INSERT INTO Subscribers (EmailAddress) VALUES ('$_POST[emailaddress]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection)) { 
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
    }

    mysql_close($connection); 
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're starting out, avoid using the `mysql_*` function family as they're now deprecated. You'd be better to start with PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: what issue you face in this code?

Comment: Your query is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting this error: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\yes.php on line 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have totaly filled in the form, it first needs to check if the submit button is clicked, then it has to send it to a database.

You also need to give you submit button a name=""

HTML code:

```
<html> 
    <body>
        <form action="postemail.php" method="post">
            Email Address: <input type="text" name="emailaddress" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add to database" /> 
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","edwardHost","password","my_database"); 
        if (!$connection) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $email = $_POST['emailaddress'];            

        $sql = "INSERT INTO Subscribers (EmailAddress) VALUES ('$email')";

        if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) { 
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
        }

        mysql_close($connection); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this

One more thing i forget last time you are missing single quete around `$_POST[emailaddress]`. In your `query`

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Subscribers (EmailAddress) VALUES ('".$_POST['emailaddress']."')";
```

Dont use `mysl function` as the are deprciated

Learn `mysqli_ function` or `PDO` Or both

Check this link for `mysql identifier` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this example using PDO in your postemail.php

```
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');

try {
    // create a new instance of a PDO connection
    $db = new PDO(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // if the connection fails, display an error message
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['emailaddress']) && !empty($_POST['emailaddress'])) {

    $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Subscribers (EmailAddress) VALUES (:emailaddress )';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue('emailaddress ', $emailaddress);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     <html> <body>
    <form action="postemail.php" method="post">  
    Email Address: <input type="text" name="emailaddress" />      
     <input type="submit" />
       </form>
      </body> </html>
  <?php $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
     if (!$connection) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   
   }
   mysql_select_db("my_database", $connection);
   $sql="INSERT INTO Subscribers (EmailAddress) VALUES ('$_POST[emailaddress]')";
   if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
   mysql_close($connection);
    ?>
```